# Partitioned date

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu yesterday on my Asus ux303lb through pendrive and partitioning 20 gb on one of my hard drives so my question is will ubuntu only be able to use the partitioned data that I used and how can I assign it more? Also I'm using a dual-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

To access ntfs drives through Ubuntu do as follows:

Boot computer with Windows 10(Steps given below are for windows 8.1 so it might be different for you)

Go to Control Panel.

Choose System and security

Choose change what power button does.

turn on fast startup is enabled.

Near to the top , you should see "View settings currently unavailable" or something similar. I am not sure because I am running ubuntu now.

Now uncheck the turn on fast startup.

Shut down the computer.

And boot Ubuntu.

you will be able to read and write to any partition on the hard drive.